# EMV - PDOL GPO conditioning

Tags: transactions, gpo, emv, mastercard

I am trying to accomplish for card to retrieve PDOL country code of terminal.
If country code of terminal is domestic response with certain GPO that uses following read records and AIP.
If terminal is international response with another GPO that use following read records and AIP that are different from domestic ones.

Relevant personalization commands (This sample is for MC application).
SELECT including PDOL 9F38039F1A02
APDU-C:
84E200024D910242A54050104D6173746572636172642044656269748701015F2D06656E657366729F38039F1A02BF0C195F5502555342035289609F4D020B0A9F6E0708400000303000E65EC82008C75743
APDU-R:9000

GPO-Domestic
APDU-C
84E200031BA00510830E18000802020018010100180303001D9726D39403688A
APDU-R  9000

GPO-International
APDU-C
84E200041BA00510830E18000802020018010100180303000C1484475FC1D420
APDU-R 9000

The part I am missing understanding how card will know which GPO to use or what is the correct way to personalize card having two GPOs.

I get error when testing the card

(010) 80 A8 00 00 04 83 02 08 40 00
 (002) 67 00

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a whole mechanism behind it that card needs to implement.
This feature is supported only by some card applications. For this particular card brand it is not normally used (their most common card application does not support PDOL for such use - you will find this information in the card application specification).

You may look at some other card applications and their specifications for details how to use card profile selection as it is being used there.